# Optimizing animations driven by onMouseMove

Tags: javascript

To add some personality to our web application, I've added a little animation on certain elements where our robot mascot peeks out from behind when the mouse moves close. To do this, I've used the onmousemove function to check how far the cursor is and animate the robot when the mouse gets close.

It works fine, but it seems terribly unoptimized to be running this function many times a second all the time when a user is moving their mouse, even when it's not animating anything. My question is, are there other common methods to do animations like this that don't use as CPU unecessarily?

You can see examples and the code on our blog here http://www.hiringthing.com/2011/10/31/buttons-with-a-surprise.html

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into `requestAnimationFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach and remove the event handler when hovering over the main section of the page so that it doesn't run when using the navigation and other areas of the page. If you have multiple elements on the page like in your demo there probably isn't much else you could do.